# How can I make an array of unique values from another, nested, array?

Tags: javascript

I bring in data from a spreadsheet into my html/javascript in an array that has multiple columns and rows. I then want to split this up into multiple smaller arrays as needed.

One of the columns has duplicates and for my purposes I need an array output of unique values. Other solutions cover only simple arrays, i.e., `[1,2,3,4]`

This works:

`const newArray = [...new Set(array)];`

This does not:

`const newArray = [...new Set(array.column)];`

Alternatively, since "this likely won't work if the `array` has object values," could I take the `array.column` and make it a seperate `array` and then apply `const newArray = [...new Set(array)];`?

```
 for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  
  dropdown[dropdown.length] = new Option(array[i].column,array[i].column)
 
 }
```

Comment: This likely won't work if `array` has object values.

Comment: You probably want `[...new Set(array.map(row => row[column]))]`

Comment: array.column is object syntax and wont work on an array

Comment: How about showing an example array and the desired result?